# How do you delete a message in rabbitmq using pika?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

How do you delete a message that is published and received, in a rabbitmq queue.
I am testing rabbitmq with python using `pika`.

How can I delete a message that is published and received?

Comment: You have to send acknowledge back of which message you received and set do auto delete option true or do your custom code for deleting message when acknowledge received.

Comment: is it possible to  set it in the configuration of rabbitmq

Comment: You can do ```task_id.revoke(termination=True)``` as params. or purge all task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899772/how-do-i-permanently-remove-a-celery-task-from-rabbitmq?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

most lucky you are not sending the ack:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)
    time.sleep( body.count('.') )
    print " [x] Done"
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag) ### <--- this one

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello')
```